# phrase for the role when someone deals with distractions for you

Tags: phrases

Is there a phrase for when someone else deals with distractions that would require  your attention. So that you can focus on something more urgent.

I want descriptions for the role of the person helping. not of the value of the work or of the person asking for help.

Comment: In spy fiction (at least British spy fiction...I'm not so sure about American), the person who deals with distractions for the agent is known as the "minder", and what they do is called "minding". Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Maybe "your collaborator is dealing with routine work" ?

Comment: That sounds like the job of a "personal assistant".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common idiom for what this person does for you is ***"runs interference"***.

From [The Free Dictionary Online](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+interference):

> Handle problems or help clear the way for another, as in "The press
> secretary runs interference for the governor."
>
> This term comes from
> football, where it refers to the blocking of defensive players by
> offensive players to let the ball carrier advance. Its figurative use
> dates from the mid-1900s.